# os.fork(): Share local variable with parent

Tags: python, linux, sockets, variables, fork

I have written a simple webserver script in python (for Linux), which creates a new child process for each HTTP(s) connection that it receives with `os.fork()`. This child then changes values of various local variables. But when the child then dies, the local variables are (logically) not set to their new value in the parent and therefore all following child processes.

One approach I came up with, was to make the child to the new parent which spawns all other children, but that would not work if I have many parallel working children.

How would I achieve to share the new values between the child and the parent and all following children? Is it possible to use IPC? If yes, do I have to create a new socket?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to use IPC. Best not to reinvent the wheel though. You should investigate the `multiprocessing` module. It supports a number of mechanisms for this purpose.  In particular, look at this example code for a model -- perhaps the `Value` or `Array` objects would provide a usable base for you: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: Thanks, @Gil. That fits my problem perfectly. Would you care of creating an answer I can accept?